# Missing procedure entry point for VariantInit during run of C++Builder application

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

When starting a compiled C++Builder application, it says it cannot find the procedure entry point for `VariantInit`, and the program does not start. After recompiling, the missing procedure varies (`_wopen`, `VariantCopyInd`, `_time`, `_write`). Using static linking of the run-time environment (Link with dynamic RTL = false, Link with run-time packages = false).

Comment: If you were truly using static linking, you would not be getting these errors. Make sure you disable BOTH the Dynamic RTL AND Runtime Packages options.

Answer (score 0):

In the project options, disable incremental link. Doing a full rebuild also works.